# Carry forward column values while inserting new rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `SQL Server` table with following columns:

```
Item Eng1 Eng2  Eng3 UpdatedDate UpdatedBy
```

Current entries in the table are:

```
item1  jacob  john  null  1/1/2000  Sheila123@gmail.com
item2  alex   null  null  2/1/2000  clint123@gmail.com
```

Now, let's say another entry for `item1` is to be inserted where `Eng2=greg` and `Eng3=tom` so that `Eng1=jacob` must be carried forward. Hence entries should now be:

```
 item1  jacob  john  null  1/1/2000  Sheila123@gmail.com
 item2  alex   null  null  2/1/2000  clint123@gmail.com
 item1  jacob  greg  tom   2/10/2000 sally123@gmail.com
```

So, basically replace column values if not the same as the new data entry else carry forward the **latest** column values that existed

Comment: Why is 'jacob' and not 'alex' your latest value for Eng1? how is the order defined?

Comment: @iceblade    alex is for 'item2' not 'item1'

Comment: @CodeMaster How do you hold the new values which are to be inserted, is it stored in a variable or a temp table?

Comment: @HemantHalwai it comes from a different software as a dataframe (so as a table)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the top 1 match, and insert the new record replacing the null values for the existing ones.

**Updated 2020-09-22. Included insert for entirely new records**

```
declare @eng1 varchar(255),
        @eng2 varchar(255) = 'greg',
        @eng3 varchar(255) = 'tom',
        @item varchar(255) = 'item1',
        @updatedDate date = '2/10/2000',
        @updatedBy varchar(255) = 'sally123@gmail.com'

Insert into yourTable (Item, Eng1, Eng2, Eng3, UpdatedDate, UpdatedBy)
select top 1    Item,
                isnull(@eng1, Eng1),
                isnull(@eng2, Eng2) ,
                isnull(@eng3, Eng3),
                UpdatedDate = @updatedDate,
                @updatedBy  
from yourTable
where Item = @item
Union
Select  @item,
        @eng1,
        @eng2,
        @eng3,
        UpdatedDate = @updatedDate,
        @updatedBy
From yourTable
where not exists (Select 1 From yourTable where Item = @item) --For entirely new records
order by UpdatedDate desc
```

Comment: Will this work for a entirely new entry for an item that does not exist yet?

Comment: For inserting an item that doesn't exist, you'd have to union with the condition no exists. I can update the query if you need it that way.